# "No module named boto3"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, boto3

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2, trying to get a python script to run that will upload files to AWS S3 buckets so I can pull them down from elsewhere later after running it through rekognition.

However, when I try to run the python script outside of the development environment I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/file.py", line 2, in <module>
      import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "boto3"
```

I've spent about 2 hours finding a resolution, including using commands like `pip install boto3` and `python -m pip install --user boto3`

I'm unsure of what fixes I can do at this point.

EDIT: It seems like its not installing boto3 to the device, any fixes for this?

Comment: I'm not experienced in dev'ing on a raspberry pi, but this sounds like either you're running `pip install boto3` on your dev computer and not the device itself, or there's more than one version of Python on the Pi and you're using `pip` instead of `pip3` or etc

Comment: It looks like whatever the process problem is, the solution can be found [here](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-raspberry-pi) in Pi's own documentation

Comment: I've been using the device itself to dev. I've also been using pip3. I don't thing its a multiple python issue. It seems to be not actually installing boto3 to the device.

Comment: That seems unlikely unless `pip install boto3` is failing. You say "when I try to run the script outside of the development environment" but also say that your development environment is on the Pi -- why do you think this is the same copy of Python?